# Perform pattern match on a generic value with type matching the return type

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

I have a problem understanding how, in the following example, the function bar1 compiles but bar2 doesn't.

```
trait Key[T] {
}

trait KeyString extends Key[String]

class Foo {
  def bar1[T]( key: Key[T] ): T = key match {
      case k: KeyString => "hallo"
      }

  /*def bar2[T](key: T): T = key match {
          case k: String => "hallo"
          }*/
}
```

Could somebody please explain, why in bar1 the compiler can figure out, that "hallo" is of type T and in bar2 that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation in `bar2` is more complex than it might appear at first. E.g. imagine that there was a subclass of `String` called `String1`. Then if `T` is `String1`, `key` would match `case k: String`, but `"hallo"` would have the wrong type. There is no such subtype, because `String` happens to be final, but it would also be strange if this compiled or not depending on finality of `String`.

`bar1` works, because this specific pattern (which is called GADT: generalized algebraic data type) has some special compiler support. This support isn't perfect: see e.g. https://gist.github.com/pchiusano/1369239.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. Just one thing I don't understand: Why would it be strange if it compiled based on the finality of String (or in general the result type). If the result type is final and equal to the matched type, it would be correct to infer that T is equal to that type, right?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer myself: T can still be the singleton type of an instance, which finality does not preclude.
See: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-127